# Is it possible to set the column width for a XSSF worksheet using Apache POI API?

Tags: apache, width, apache-poi, xssf

I need to generate a MS Excel 2007+ file from my application according to a given pattern provided by management. Most of the work is done, but I have to set the column width to 11,34 centimeters. I tried to use the `setColumnWidth(int columnIndex, int width)` method, but regardless of the value I provide it does not work. JavaDoc says:

> Set the width (in units of 1/256th of a character width)
>
> The maximum column width for an individual cell is 255 characters. This value represents the number of characters that can be displayed in a cell that is formatted with the standard font.

How to do this?

Comment: Did you check to make sure that the column isn't being set to autosize automatically?  Make sure that you are not doing this call in your code, `sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnIndex);`

Comment: Hi, I haven't found any similar calls on my code. I'm wondering if there's a way to convert centimeters to "character width" instead? Or this doesn't makes sense, whatsoever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was mistaken from the very beggining! My (terrible!) bad! Width columns were already being set, but thought not! All it took as a simple "rule of three" and I was set.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I understand your problem now, your business requirements state that you must set the width of the column based on standard Excel font character width.

The way I would approach this would be to use the Print Screen key on an example in Excel, then paste into Paint or a similar program and count pixel width.  I would then use the ruler tool to measure pixels/cm and use the resulting number as my fixed column width.

This will probably involve a little bit of trial and error to get right.

Now with that said I will share my personal opinion that I feel this a LAZY and WEAK business requirement.  What is "standard font"?  Which version of Excel?  This requirement is open to entirely too much developer interpretation.

Comment: The method I use to build the sheet's layout is [link]http://pastebin.com/iaqWhHg6[/link]. But, the requirement I have is to make the output so my manager can just copy-paste the resulting formatted set of columns into a report to the board. The current standard is so one of the colums is much bigger (the code does not reflect this), but I need to programmatically set the column's width.